# Firefox opens up about a dozen connections on launch

Tags: firefox

I just opened a firefox "private" window and without loading any website I observe the following connections being made:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo netstat -tunp | grep 443
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.104:53622     35.82.87.100:443        ESTABLISHED 2322/firefox        
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.104:34462     18.66.139.31:443        ESTABLISHED 2322/firefox        
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.104:53624     35.82.87.100:443        ESTABLISHED 2322/firefox        
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.104:55112     35.164.91.82:443        ESTABLISHED 2322/firefox        
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.104:37062     34.117.237.239:443      ESTABLISHED 2322/firefox        
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo netstat -tunp | grep 80
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.104:47760     34.107.221.82:80        ESTABLISHED 2322/firefox        
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.104:47764     34.107.221.82:80        ESTABLISHED 2322/firefox        
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.104:56462     93.184.220.29:80        ESTABLISHED 2322/firefox        
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.104:57978     104.76.220.129:80       ESTABLISHED 2322/firefox        
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.104:56460     93.184.220.29:80        ESTABLISHED 2322/firefox
```

I did some looking up and those addresses seem to belong to amazon, google, ripe and amakai.

Why is firefox opening a bunch of (persistent) connections to these servers?

#### EDIT:

I turned off all addons and only a couple connections disappeared.

I used `tcpdump` to get a vague idea of what's going on at port 80 and indeed it is hitting some google amazon and akamai servers at addresses like

```
a104-76-220-193.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com
82.221.107.34.bc.googleusercontent.com
sof02s33-in-f3.1e100.net
```

Comment: It may be related to your addons.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the actual data being sent? Those appear to be clear-text connections (plaintext HTTP on port 80), you should be able to see the actual hostnames and URLs within. (I'm tempted to guess it's OCSP.)

Comment: I added some info to the question.

Comment: Now use tcpdump with `-A`, or even Wireshark, to see what's deeper inside the packets (e.g. HTTP headers).

Comment: You could look them up in WhoIs. For example, https://www.whois.com/whois/35.82.87.100 resolves to Amazon Technologies... and one of the search providers in Firefox is Amazon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this knowledge base document](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Connections_established_on_startup_-_Firefox) Firefox may establish connections on startup for the following reasons:

- A loopback connection (to IP address 127.0.0.1) on non-Unix machines [1](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Connections_established_on_startup_-_Firefox). The browser is communicating normally with itself, and it is not recommended this be blocked.
- Loading Live Bookmarks. Deleting all Live Bookmarks will stop these connections.
- Checking for application updates. "Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Update" provides options to disable update checks.
- Loading home page. Setting the homepage to a blank page or a local page will stop this connection.
- Updating phishing sites database. Setting browser.safebrowsing.enabled to false in about:config will disable this feature.
- Prefetching links if the page it's on defines any. See the Prefetch FAQ and network.prefetch-next for further information. To disable pings in prefetched links, see browser.send_pings.
- Updating the Add-ons Blocklist. Setting extensions.blocklist.enabled to false in about:config will disable this feature.
- Updating metadata for installed add-ons. Setting extensions.getAddons.cache.enabled to false in about:config will disable this feature.
- Firefox Health Report data.

The page was last modified in 2013, so there may be more reasons nowadays.